What is the difference between a minor, a cofactor, an algebraic cofactor, and a principal minor?
What is the difference between a minor, a cofactor, an algebraic cofactor, and a principal minor in linear algebra?
I have an mth-order determinant, and I delete n rows and n columns (m > n). The nth-order determinant obtained by deleting these n rows and n columns is called what, and the remaining (m-n)th-order determinant is called what? In my book, I see that the nth-order determinant is referred to as a minor, and the remaining (m-n)th-order determinant is called a cofactor. If this (m-n)th-order determinant includes a sign, it is called an algebraic cofactor. I'm not sure if it's a translation issue that's causing the confusion, and I am currently very puzzled.

"Algebraic cofactor" just means cofactor. Cofactors are the $(n-1) \times (n-1)$ minors with some signs attached. Principal minors are the minors of a square matrix where the rows and columns have the same indices.

Your book appears to be using less standard terminology (at least in English).
Usually, a subdeterminant obtained from a determinant or (possibly rectangular) matrix by selecting certain rows and columns (and not multiplying by a separate sign factor) is just called a minor determinant. The minor obtained by retaining the selected rows and columns is sometimes called a retainer minor, and that obtained by rejecting them (i.e. retaining the other rows and columns) is called a rejector minor. Clearly, you can do everything with either retainer or rejector minors, so most authors just pick one. If the selected rows and columns have the same indices, then it is a principal minor. The product of a minor with an appropriate sign factor is usually just called a cofactor.
As an example, consider the $5\times 5$ determinant
$$A=\begin{vmatrix}
1&2&3&4&5\\
6&7&8&9&10\\
11&12&13&14&15\\
16&17&18&19&20\\
21&22&23&24&25
\end{vmatrix}$$
The $2\times 2$ retainer minor obtained from rows $1,3$ and columns $2,5$ might be written
$$A_{\{1,3\},\{2,5\}}=\begin{vmatrix}
2&5\\
12&15
\end{vmatrix}$$
while the corresponding $3\times 3$ rejector minor might be written
$$A_{\overline{\{1,3\}},\overline{\{2,5\}}}=A_{\{2,4,5\},\{1,3,4\}}=\begin{vmatrix}
6&8&9\\
16&18&19\\
21&23&24
\end{vmatrix}$$
Neither of these are principal minors, but $A_{\{1,3\},\{1,3\}}$ is. The cofactor obtained from rows $1,3$ and columns $2,5$ is
$$(-1)^{1+3+2+5}A_{\{1,3\},\{2,5\}}$$
However, the term "cofactor" is most naturally understood in the context of the Laplace cofactor expansion and related results. For example if we expand $A$ along rows $1,3$, we obtain
$$A=\sum_{1\le k_1<k_2\le 5}(-1)^{1+3+k_1+k_2}A_{\{1,3\},\{k_1,k_2\}}\cdot A_{\{2,4,5\},\overline{\{k_1,k_2\}}}$$
Each term in this sum is a product of two factors: a minor and a cofactor (which factor has the sign associated with it to be considered the cofactor versus the minor does not really matter, as there is duality here).
